# How to solve "clipboard buffer is full and output lost" error in R running in Windows?

Tags: r

I am trying to copy some data directly from R to the clipboard, in my Windows machine. I found in some sites that using file="clipboard" would work. And it does, but for very small datasets.

For example:

If I copy a small dataset (100 obs), it works smoothly.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(100))
write.table(df1, file="clipboard", sep="\t", col.names=NA)
```

But if I increase the observations to 10,000, it fails:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(10000))
write.table(df1, file="clipboard", sep="\t", col.names=NA)
```

The error is:

> Warning message: In .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, r

Any workaround to this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you type `?connections` you will find your answer.

This is the relevant part:

"When writing to the clipboard, the output is copied to the clipboard only when the connection is closed or flushed. There is a 32Kb limit on the text to be written to the clipboard. This can be raised by using e.g. file("clipboard-128") to give 128Kb."

So, the solution is pretty straigthforward:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(10000))
write.table(df1, file="clipboard-16384", sep="\t", col.names=NA)
```

Note that the number of Kb is just an example, so you can change it as you need (I put 2^14 that should be more than enough for your data set, but you can increase it even more. Not sure which is the hard limit, though. Maybe physical memory?)

Comment: Awesome! I bumped it to `file = paste0("clipboard-", 2^20)` to support 1 Gb and just after that pasted 500.000 cells into Excel from R :)

Comment: In my case with `2^20` excel gives me the error `Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data`, but with `2^19` it works fine. It's strange because the error remains for small amounts of data, so it seems these calls to `write.table` do "something different".

Answer (score 6):

I like to use only the memory I need.  So I let the object.size() function figure out what I need. In addition, I usually like to source a function that I like to use frequently.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(10000))
write.excel <- function(x,row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE,...) {
  write.table(x,file = paste0("clipboard-", object.size(x)),sep="\t",row.names=row.names,col.names=col.names,...)
}

write.excel(df1, FALSE, TRUE)
```

It would probably be prudent to check the object.size is smaller than the memory.size. And let this thing fail if necessary.

Hope this helps.