# R is there an easy way to copy-paste tables from R to email / word / google docs?

Tags: r

I often need to do a quick share of a table into an email or to a word or google document.  I use the package `clipr` and built a function like this to put stuff on my clipboard:

```
function (x = .Last.value) 
{
    clipr::write_clip(x)
    message("Value copied to clipboard")
}
```

When I do this with a table and paste it into the things mentioned above, the spacing is all messed up when it goes to a plain text editor (ie Spark, my email client) or to an editor that has table functionality (MS Word / Google Docs).

Is there a way to do an easy copy paste that preserves the table spacing for plain text?  Or formats as a table in word/gdocs?

Answer (score 2):

I regularly use the function below which **elikesprogramming** mentions in his answer on this question ([How to solve "clipboard buffer is full and output lost" error in R running in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035119/how-to-solve-clipboard-buffer-is-full-and-output-lost-error-in-r-running-in-wi)) and it appears as a table object when pasting into Excel, Word or Outlook.

```
write.table(data, "clipboard-16384", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: I've tried this but nothing ends up on the clipboard (no error message though).  Are you on mac or windows? I'm using Mac

Comment: Windows unfortunately. write_clip looks to have an argument called 'breaks' which may fit your purpose: ```write_clip(x, breaks = "\t")```